# MySQL, join together two subsets of one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with query building...

I have one table, that contains rows: name, start, end, ref, alt, patientNo.
The example data looks like that:

```
chr1, 10, 10, A, B, 9999;
chr1, 12, 12, B, A, 9999;
chr1, 18, 18, A, B, 9999;
chr1, 29, 29, C, B, 9999;
chr1, 10, 10, A, A, 8888;
chr1, 12, 12, A, B, 8888;
chr2, 18, 18, D, C, 8888;
chr2, 29, 29, A, B, 8888;
```

end so on...

I need to build a query, that compare patients between each other.
i.e.:
if (chr1, start, end, alt of patient 9999) = (chr1, start, end, alt of patient 8888)
return a row...

any idea how to bulid such query?
thanks

### Edit:

OK, I still have a problem.
I have ten CSV files with genomic data of patients.
Each file contains about 70000 rows.
I put data from CSV files into MySQL database (so my database contains one table with 700000 rows).

Now I need to filter this data. There are many columns, e.g.:
**name**(varchar), **start**(int), **end**(int), **ref**(varchar), **alt**(varchar), **patientNo**(varchar).
An example statement: `SELECT name, start, end, ref, alt, patientNo FROM mytable`; returns following data:

```
chr1, 10, 10, A, C, 9999;
chr1, 12, 12, T, T, 9999;
chr2, 18, 18, A, T, 9999;
chr2, 29, 29, C, C, 9999;
chr3, 10, 10, A, G, 9999;
chr3, 12, 12, A, C, 9999;
chr1, 18, 18, G, C, 8888;
chr2, 29, 29, A, G, 8888;
chr2, 10, 10, A, G, 8888;
chr3, 12, 12, G, A, 8888;
chr1, 18, 18, A, G, 666z;
chr2, 29, 29, C, G, 666z;
chr3, 10, 10, A, A, 666z;
chr4, 12, 12, A, G, 666z;
chr5, 18, 18, T, C, 666z;
chr1, 29, 29, A, G, 44a4;
chr1, 10, 10, A, G, 44a4;
chr2, 12, 12, G, A, 44a4;
chr2, 18, 18, A, G, 44a4;
chr1, 29, 29, C, G, 3333;
chr1, 10, 10, A, A, 3333;
chr1, 12, 12, A, G, 3333;
chr1, 18, 18, T, C, 3333;
chr2, 29, 29, A, G, 3333;
```

I need to extract rows which have an unique letter in **alt** column, at speceific **name** and **start** position, an **alt** letter, that is unique for a patient.
If I join columns

```
SELECT p1.name, p1.start, p1.alt, p2.alt, p3.alt, p4.alt, p5.alt 
FROM mytable p1, mytable p2, mytable p3, mytable p4, mytable p5 
WHERE ( p1.patientNo = "9999" and p2.patientNo = "8888" and 
        p3.patientNo = "666z" and p4.patientNo = "44a4" and
        p5.patientNo = "3333") ;
```

I obtine results, e.g.:

```
chr1 10 A A A A A
chr1 13 G G G G G
chr2 17 A A G A A
chr2 19 A A G G A
chr3 38 A C A T T
```

so that means:

- On the position start=10, each patient p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 has got an A letter. That's good we skip this row
- The same with start posiotion 13.
- On the position start=17, patient p3 has got unique letter G, so we
  put this row to the result table
- In the next row (19) there is no unique letter, we skip it.
- In the row (38), the "C" is an unique letter so we put patient p2 to
  the result table.

So finally, the result of above example should looks like:

```
chr2, 17, G, 666z
chr3, 19, C, 8888
```

Is it possible to construct a query, that will return such result from the original table?

Comment: Please explain this a bit more. What is `start`, what is `end` and what is `alt of patient`? What do you mean by comparing patients between each other? Comparing all patients against all patients?

Comment: What you want to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, a.start, a.end, a.alt, a.patientNo,
    b.name, b.start, b.end, b.alt, b.patientNo
FROM patient AS a, patient AS b
WHERE a.name = b.name
AND a.start = b.start
AND a.end = b.end
AND a.alt = b.alt
AND a.patientNo < b.patientNo
ORDER by a.name
```

with the following form:

```
SELECT <Columns> FROM <Table(s)> WHERE <Condition> ORDER BY <Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried, but see:

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.* FROM tablePatients p1, tablePatients p2 WHERE p1.chr1 = p2.chr1  AND p1.start = p1.start AND p1.end = p2.end AND p1.ref = p2.ref AND p1.alt = p2.alt
```